# How to use scipy.optimize.bisect() when function has additional parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, bisect

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html), I should be able to bisect a function with multiple parameters as long as I pass said parameters to bisect() using args=(). However, I just can't make it work and I didn't manage to find an example of using this function in such a scenario.

My function is of shape $f(a,x)$, where the user inputs $a$ and the program finds a root in variable x using scipy.optimize.bisect().

I tried passing it as:

```
scipy.optimize.bisect(f,-a,a,args=(a,))
```

But that didn't exactly work.

Comment: Please clarify (in your question), what "But that didn't exactly work." means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `args` arguments are added *after* the argument the root finding operates on, not before. If you want to perform root-finding on the last argument instead of the first, you'll need to write a wrapper function that adapts your function's signature to what `bisect` expects.

```
def g(x, a):
    return f(a, x)

do_whatever_with(scipy.optimize.bisect(g, -a, a, args=(a,))
```